# i was upgrading parrot os and it failed realtek driver and said to use dpkg -a --configure

Tags: operating-system, repository, driver, parrot

dpkg --configure -a
Setting up realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms (5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08-0parrot1) ...
Removing old realtek-rtl8188eus-5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08 DKMS files...
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08/source/dkms.conf)
Module realtek-rtl8188eus-5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08 for kernel 5.18.0-14parrot1-amd64 (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

8188eu.ko:

- Uninstallation

  - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.18.0-14parrot1-amd64/updates/dkms/
- Original module

  - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
  - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
    depmod....
    Deleting module realtek-rtl8188eus-5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08 completely from the DKMS tree.
    Loading new realtek-rtl8188eus-5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08 DKMS files...
    Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/usr/src/realtek-rtl8188eus-5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08/dkms.conf)
    Building for 6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64
    Building initial module for 6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64
    Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08/source/dkms.conf)
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64 (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20220829.4ba8e08/build/make.log for more information.
    dpkg: error processing package realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms (--configure):
    installed realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms

VERSION ID5.1
VERSION 5.1 Electro Ara
VERSION CODENAME=ara
6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64

any ideas for trouble shoot

Answer (score 1):

Kernel VERSION ID5.1 VERSION 5.1 Electro Ara VERSION CODENAME=ara 6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64 not supported to that device i got some problem with you, downgrade to the stable kernel is the fast way solve this error

Answer (score 1):

deleting the old not installable packages will fix it use:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/realtek-rtl8*
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/r8168-8.050.03/
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be a real pain in the ass to fix so the most straightforward way to fix it as a whole is to recompile the kernel for Parrot os. download the lastest kernel from kernel.org, untar it and then recompile it and reinstall with a couple of commands and it should work as expected with no errors.